# PHP Can't get https content

Tags: php, ssl, https, file-get-contents

I was working on using an api in php.

This is what I got for so far:

```
$keybotlink = file_get_contents('https://steamgaug.es/api/v2');
echo $keybotlink;
```

(Not much :D), Anyways, if I try to run this, The page is empty.

If I try to do

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);
```

This is the output:

```
openssl: yes 
http wrapper: yes 
https wrapper: yes 
wrappers: array(22) 
      { [0]=> string(13) "compress.zlib" 
        [1]=> string(4) "dict" 
        [2]=> string(3) "ftp" 
        [3]=> string(4) "ftps" 
        [4]=> string(6) "gopher" 
        [5]=> string(4) "http" 
        [6]=> string(5) "https" 
        [7]=> string(4) "imap" 
        [8]=> string(5) "imaps" 
        [9]=> string(4) "pop3" 
        [10]=> string(5) "pop3s" 
        [11]=> string(4) "rtsp" 
        [12]=> string(4) "smtp" 
        [13]=> string(5) "smtps" 
        [14]=> string(6) "telnet" 
        [15]=> string(4) "tftp" 
        [16]=> string(3) "php" 
        [17]=> string(4) "file" 
        [18]=> string(4) "glob" 
        [19]=> string(4) "data" 
        [20]=> string(3) "zip" 
        [21]=> string(4) "phar" 
    }
```

Thanks, Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow `https` wrapper `php_openssl` extension mustbe enabled and `allow_url_fopen` must be set to on.

Add below lines in php.ini file if it does not exist:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_fopen = On
```

You can also use `curl` for this:

```
function getData($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if($result === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

print_r( json_decode( getData('https://steamgaug.es/api/v2') ) );
```

Comment: I cant do extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_fopen = On, Its not my own server.

Comment: If I try getData, I get again, A blank screen.

Comment: Are you doing `echo getData('https://steamgaug.es/api/v2');` because that works for me. Or better still `print_r( json_decode( getData('https://steamgaug.es/api/v2') ) );`

Comment: Have updated my post to check curl error. Execute it and check what error are you getting.

Comment: Curl error: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Answer (score 0):

For download content from HTTPS sites use folowing code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://steamgaug.es/api/v2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// if you want to connet to https page you can skip SSL verification by setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to 0
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
// if you want to fetch result to a variable use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// grab URL and pass it to the $output variable
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

CURL is very good and full of options tool to working with HTTP(S) requests.

Comment: If I paste that in .php, I get "Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/tf2bots/public_html/test.php on line 3

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/tf2bots/public_html/test.php on line [ALL LINES]

Comment: Check code again, the top of the code was missing and is now visible

Comment: I don't know why stackoverflow have been ate two first lines :(

Comment: It shows the JSON response to me with the above code. Are you sure, you have enabled curl ? Also, try to clear your cache.

Comment: try to put the code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of your script